# ¿Cómo puedo extraer una cadena de caracteres con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo una duda, es posible extraer una cadena de caracteres con javascript, tengo un label, y quiero sacar las primeras dos letras para almacenarlas en una variable y luego mostrarlas en otro label.

Comment: Podrías añadir un ejemplo mínimo de lo que deseas. Las letras al comienzo no importa si son mayúsculas o minúsculas?

Comment: No, por ejemplo tengo esta palabra en un Label Gabriel García Marquez y solo deseo extraer las letras "Ga" de preferencia sería mejor que el resultado fuera en mayúscula

Comment: Hola DMya. tu pregunta es muy amplia, no por la dificultad si no porque has de mostrar lo que has intentado y los errores o problemas encontrados. Mira [ask] para mejorar esta o futuras preguntas. Un saludo

Comment: asociación: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola si es posible extraer caracteres de un string utilizando el método `substr()`.

Por ejemplo. Con el siguiente fragmento de código.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var palabra = document.getElementById("palabra").value;
    var letras;
    letras = palabra.substr(0,2);
    alert(letras);    
    document.getElementById("aux").innerHTML = letras;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Haz Click en el boton para obtener las primeras 2 letras del String</p>

<input type="text" name="palabra" id="palabra">
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Obtener caracteres</button>
<br>
<label id="aux" name="aux">Valor</label>
</body>
</html>
```

En el `input` con `id` palabra ingresamos nuestro `String`.

Seguido en el evento `onclick` de nuestro botón hacemos uso de `myFunction()`, el cual mediante el uso de :

> var palabra = document.getElementById("palabra").value;

Vamos y recuperamos lo que contenga el textbox y lo guardamos en la variable `palabra`.
Para después en la variable `letras` mediante el método `substr()` guardar las primeras 2 letras de nuestro `String` y finalmente con:

> document.getElementById("aux").innerHTML = letras;

Asignamos el valor al elemento `label` con id `aux` el contenido de la variable.

Comment: Muchas gracias :D, solo una duda, ¿Pueden aparecer ambas letras en mayúscula?

Comment: @DMya a que te refieres? A qué el resultado lo de en letras mayúsculas? De ser así puedes usar `String.toUpperCase();`

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como se comenta en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript), ECMAScript 6 introdujo [String.prototype.includes:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
const string = "foo";
const substring = "oo";

console.log(string.includes(substring));
```

Internet Explorer no soporta `includes` sin embargo en entornos más antiguos se puede usar [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), que retorna -1 cuando no se encontró la cadena a buscar.

```js
var string = "foo";
var substring = "oo";

console.log(string.indexOf(substring) !== -1);
```